# Inserting special characters into SQL database from form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am submitting form values into a database using PHP but I am running into an issue when user's enter special characters such as an apostrophe. For example if someone enters `Bill's Pet Supply` into organization, there will be an SQL error.

Here is my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $organization = $_POST['organization'];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO submissions VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :organization)");

    $sql->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
    $sql->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $sql->bindValue(':organization', $organization);

    $sql->execute();
}

$conn->close();
```

How can I change this code so that apostrophes and other special characters will be supported?

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO, and use the parameter binding.

Comment: See if this info helps: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: There's two interface libraries:  mysqli and PDO. And it looks like you are attempting to use PDO supported features which aren't supported in mysqli.   I don't believe mysqli supports named placeholders like PDO does e.g. **`:firstname`**. With mysqli, use positional placeholder **`?`**. PDO has a **`bindValue`** function. mysqli uses **`bind_param`** function. See the example in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.  Both PDO and mysqli provide support for those.

Your SQL text would look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (firstname, lastname, email, organization)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

If you are using mysqli

[mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

[myslqi_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[myslqi_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

```
$sth = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$sth) {
  // handle error
}
$sth->bind_param("ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $organization);
if( $res = $sth->execute() ) {
  // process resultset
}
```

Similar functions available in PDO, but you can use "bind value" instead of "bind param".

---

If there's some reason you can't use prepared statements with bind placeholders, then at a minimum, you will need to *properly escape* any potentially unsafe values included in the SQL text.

If you are using mysqli, then generating the SQL text would look something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (firstname, lastname, email, organization)
VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $firstname )
  . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $lastname ) 
  . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $email )
  . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $organization )
  . "')";
```

But don't do that. Use a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I have updated my code using mysqli prepared statements but now I am getting a 500 error when I submit the form. Could you take a look and let me know if you see any issues?

Comment: Never mind, used your updated answer and it's working great now, thanks again!